# jquery .live on load function

Tags: jquery

I need a way to use the jquery .live() function to act on a elements that is loaded via ajax.

For eg. a div is loaded via ajax .load()

Normally we use .live() with a  event to handle ajax loaded data, but I need to handle this div on every time the ajax data is loaded with load event.

following is my code that doesn't work, but I want to do something like this:

```
    $('#hidden').live('load',function(){
        hiddenInfo = $('#hidden').text();
    });
```

Comment: +1: This is actually not a bad question. Lots of people want to know when something is *Ajax loaded*, but know in a generic way.

Comment: You do realize that `.live()` has been deprecated and removed from jQuery, right?

Answer (score 3):

A more general approach is to broadcast a custom event, inside the Ajax success event, using `trigger`  so you *can* use `on` (in preference to `live`, please);

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#hidden").html(data);
    $("#hidden").trigger("panelloaded");   // Just pick a name not already used
}
```

Then you can have

```
$('#hidden').on('panelloaded',function(){
    hiddenInfo = $('#hidden').text();
});
```

or a delegated version if the element itself can change:

```
$(document).on('panelloaded', '#hidden', function(){
    hiddenInfo = $('#hidden').text();
});
```

*In theory, you could use "load" as the event name (and not change your code at all), but I am not sure what other clashes you might have as `load` is such a common term.*

Answer (score 0):

Just do something in the AJAX callback once it's loaded, eg:

```
success: function(data) {
    $("#hidden").html(data);
    hiddenInfo = data.text; //or whatever
}
```

Or hook into the global AJAX complete event to do something everytime an AJAX event finishes.